# Legend for pie chart is displayed while legend for bar chart is not displayed, only the change is kind of graph

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization

Code for both the graphs is the same only the kind of chart is changed. The first image is of a pie chart with legend being displayed while the second image is of bar chart but the legend is not being displayed. Why?[image: Pie Chart]

[image: Bar graph]

Comment: This is the expected output. Each bar in your plot is representing a `Group_ID.`  'B_1', 'B_2' etc is shown using `xlabel`. That's it. I would say that in the case of Pie plot, you are showing the same information twice!. 'B_1', 'B_2' etc. are shown two times, which does not make any sense from the visualization point of view.

Comment: Yes, the same information is being shown, that I know. But why the legend is not shown in case of bar plot but is shown in case of pie plot @RaviJoshi?

Comment: There are various kinds of plots having different meanings and use cases. You need to understand the use case behind bar chart. For example, you are doing human population analysis of a country. You have two groups, male and female. In each group, you have defined certain age groups, let say 0-15, 16-30, 31-45, 46-60, 61+. Now when you plot this data, there will be only two legends, male and female. For each group, male/female, you will have 5 bars. Below each bar in the x-axis, you will have age-groups as labels. In short, your data is having only 1 group, so you are seeing only one legend.

Comment: I got your point @RaviJoshi. But I have two groups in my dataset 'absolute beginner' and 'beginner' and these two groups have further 29 subgroups (like you divided male/female population into 5 subgroups) among which 5 are shown above in the graph. Your given example is matching with my data.